# hosting - how to get domain name for my website from home?

Tags: apache, dns, hosting, web-hosting, rhel7

i want to set up a server for hosting a static website (html/css/javascript), so i install RHEL 7 on my computer , and i install apache2.4.6 , also i forward the ports 80 (for apache ) and 22 (for ssh), after i set up a dns server from [this tutorial](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-setup-a-named-dns-service-on-redhat-7-linux-server)  , and when i test the dns server with :

```
dig @192.168.1.110 www.example.com
```

i get this output :

```
; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-51.el7_4.2 <<>> @192.168.1.110 www.example.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 46518
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.example.com.       IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.example.com.    10800   IN  A   1.1.1.1

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
example.com.        10800   IN  NS  ns2.rhel7.local.
example.com.        10800   IN  NS  ns1.rhel7.local.

;; Query time: 31 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.110#53(192.168.1.110)
;; WHEN: Fri Mar 02 18:48:12 WET 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 107
```

so i think all is good , after i create in **/var/www/** one directory called **sites** (where i gnna past all my website ) and i copy tow website ( directories ) inside this directory : **site1** and **utopic_flowers**.
now i can access to my website from another computer (outside my network) with this syntax :

> public_ip_address/sites/site1/

and

> public_ip_address/sites/utopic_flowers/

now how can i set a domain name for those websites , where i can access to it by this syntax :

> www.site1.com

and

> www.utopic_flowers.com

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create config files for your websites.
In ubuntu they are stored in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` folder.
After you will create 2 new config files for your websites you will need to enable them with `a2ensite websiteconfigname` command then restart apache2 service.

Those links might help.
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts#step-four-%E2%80%94-create-new-virtual-host-files